# Zombie movie: guy with a sniper rifle helps a family in a warehouse, airplanes fly over frequently including for supply drops

Tags: story-identification, movie, zombie

There was this zombie movie I watched a while ago.

There was a guy that had a sniper rifle on him and he finds a family and lives in a warehouse or something big with poles. At some point there were planes passing over; there was a supply drop and he had to get the medicine for the family.

At one point there was a zombie girl with red eyes who said, "Have you see my baby? Let me in," and kept repeating it until he shot her.

Then, at the end the military came in and told him to speak, so he said something, and then the military shot him with a dart and brought everyone in to some place.

Also there was a point where the guy goes out when he sees an airplane fly over. A zombie attacks him, and the zombies are really strong. Then one guy came out and broke a board on its back and then killed it with a screwdriver or something.

Answer (score 7):

I believe you are thinking of [*State of Emergency*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_Emergency_(2011_film)) (2011).

*State of Emergency* is the story of a man fighting against people exposed to (presumed) military chemical agents. The exposed are erratic and behave much like traditional zombies. The main character carries a sniper rifle and hides out in a large stable barn and a warehouse. The military, in order to control the incident, institutes the titular state of emergency and quarantines the area - mainly showing strength through the presence of helicopters and aircraft. The helicopters drop supplies in special supply pods to help the survivors. I do not recall a family in the story, however there are a group of survivors that could be confused with a family.

Sounds pretty close to what you are looking for. I found the movie pretty enjoyable as a low-energy slow burn thriller/horror film.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this answer (explain how it matches the description given in the question, provide quotes and images)? That will help the asker and others who might come here identify whether it really is the book they’re looking for.

Comment: Just a few quotes from the Wikipedia article would show that this matches several of the details in the question, for example.

Comment: @Adamant I expanded on the reasons why I thought it matches. Thanks. A question though - does horror count as fantasy? Has there ever been a discussion on to just what sci-fi fantasy actually encompasses? Thanks again

Comment: “Horror” is an atmosphere. A horror movie can be science fiction (as this one is), fantasy (like “Nightmare on Elm Street”), or neither (like “Saw” or “Jaws”).

Comment: @Adamant good to know that horror related questions are acceptable here

Comment: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/does-fantasy-include-the-supernatural-what-about-horror and http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9667/51379

Comment: Yes thank you it is State of Emergency

Comment: @Shadow If this is the movie you were looking for, you accept Withywindle's answer by clicking on the check mark below the voting buttons on the left. ^_^